# Double-tap recognition just in subview (not main view)

Tags: swift, view, swift2, uitapgesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

I am trying to get Swift 2 (XCode 7) to recognize a double tap on a subview which is supposed to go to fullscreen after the double-tap.

I have used the code below where subView is a view that I have dragged onto the main view.

This code will initially just print "Tap" to the console to check.

However, wherever on the screen I double-tap I get the result. The tap recognition is not just restricted to the subview as intended.

Can anyone shed some light?

```
@IBOutlet var subView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.initializeGestureRecognizer()

}

func initializeGestureRecognizer() {

    let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: Selector("recognizeTapGesture:"))

    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

    subView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}

func recognizeTapGesture(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("Tap")

}
```

Comment: did you add self.view.addSubview(tsubView)?

Comment: Thanks for that. This actually helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian Ettelt anyhow if i give you the correct answer,it is very helpful for others.

```
func initializeGestureRecognizer() 
{

   let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: Selector("recognizeTapGesture:"))

   tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

   subView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

   self.view.addSubview(subView)

}
```

Please tick and up vote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
func recognizeTapGesture(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.view == subView {
       print("Tap")
    }
}
```